# Flask Redirect going to list of domains

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, nginx, flask

I've been working on a Flask app, and in deployment I've had to use Gunicorn and Nginx. It's now accessible, however whenever redirecting from within Flask, the address redirected to is a list consisting of my domain twice, e.g
`https://cards.jellywx.co.uk,card.jellywx.co.uk/game?id=12`.

My configuration file for Nginx (in sites-available) looks like

```
  server {
        listen 80;

        server_name http://cards.jellywx.co.uk;
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name https://cards.jellywx.co.uk;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cards.jellywx.co.uk/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cards.jellywx.co.uk/privkey.pem;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /socket.io {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/socket.io;

        }

        location /static {
                alias /var/www/cards-against-humanity/app/static;
                expires 30d;
        }
}
```

and for redirects, I'm simply using `return redirect( url_for( 'game', id=game_id ) )`

Source is available at https://github.com/jellywx/cards-against-humanity

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Nginx Error Log:

```
2018/08/29 14:25:26 [notice] 5780#5780: signal process started
2018/08/29 12:32:01 [warn] 5891#5891: server name "http://cards.jellywx.co.uk" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cards:4
2018/08/29 12:32:01 [warn] 5891#5891: server name "https://cards.jellywx.co.uk" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cards:12
2018/08/29 12:32:01 [warn] 5891#5891: could not build optimal proxy_headers_hash, you should increase either proxy_headers_hash_max_size: 512 or proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size
2018/08/29 12:32:01 [notice] 5891#5891: signal process started
2018/08/29 12:55:01 [error] 5892#5892: *1258 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.24.5.236, server: https://cards.jellywx.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "cards.jellywx.co.uk"
2018/08/29 13:23:53 [error] 5892#5892: *1328 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 82.24.5.236, server: https://cards.jellywx.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "cards.jellywx.co.uk"
2018/08/29 13:23:54 [error] 5892#5892: *1328 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 82.24.5.236, server: https://cards.jellywx.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "cards.jellywx.co.uk"
2018/08/29 13:24:12 [error] 5892#5892: *1328 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 82.24.5.236, server: https://cards.jellywx.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "cards.jellywx.co.uk"
2018/08/29 13:24:13 [error] 5892#5892: *1328 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 82.24.5.236, server: https://cards.jellywx.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "cards.jellywx.co.uk"
2018/08/29 13:24:58 [warn] 6537#6537: server name "http://cards.jellywx.co.uk" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cards:4
2018/08/29 13:24:58 [warn] 6537#6537: server name "https://cards.jellywx.co.uk" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cards:12
2018/08/29 13:24:58 [warn] 6537#6537: could not build optimal proxy_headers_hash, you should increase either proxy_headers_hash_max_size: 512 or proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size
2018/08/29 13:24:58 [notice] 6537#6537: signal process started
root@vps578947:/var/log/nginx#
```

Systemd Log from Gunicorn:

```
Aug 29 13:27:05 vps578947 systemd[1]: Stopped cards-against-humanity.service.
Aug 29 13:27:05 vps578947 systemd[1]: cards-against-humanity.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 29 13:27:05 vps578947 systemd[1]: cards-against-humanity.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 29 13:27:05 vps578947 systemd[1]: Failed to start cards-against-humanity.service.
Aug 29 13:27:08 vps578947 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cards-against-humanity.service:2: Unknown lvalue 'Name' in section 'Unit'
Aug 29 13:27:08 vps578947 systemd[1]: Started cards-against-humanity.service.
Aug 29 13:27:09 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]: [2018-08-29 13:27:09 +0000] [6740] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Aug 29 13:27:09 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]: [2018-08-29 13:27:09 +0000] [6740] [INFO] Listening at: https://127.0.0.1:8000 (6740)
Aug 29 13:27:09 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]: [2018-08-29 13:27:09 +0000] [6740] [INFO] Using worker: eventlet
Aug 29 13:27:09 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]: [2018-08-29 13:27:09 +0000] [6763] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6763
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]: [2018-08-29 13:43:14,687] ERROR in app: Exception on /game [GET]
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     raise value
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/var/www/cards-against-humanity/app/routes.py", line 225, in game
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     request.args.get('id')
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 923, in get
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     ident, loading.load_on_pk_identity)
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 984, in _get_impl
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]:     if len(primary_key_identity) != len(mapper.primary_key):
Aug 29 13:43:14 vps578947 gunicorn3[6740]: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Are you sure that splitting into two server directives in a nginx conf is a correct way? [Official nginx example uses different approach](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server).

Comment: could you put the las lines of `/var/log/gunicorn/<your-error-log-file>' and the last lines from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`? By the way I recommend a different approach for nginx. You should leave the default nginx.conf the same and create a specific config file for your app and store on '/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-app-name`and `/etc/nginx/sites-enable/your-app-name` This article might help: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux

Comment: @Fian I've been following the guide here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux . Let me check the docs too

Comment: @jalazbe Sorry, my bad, that's the guide I'm following but I didn't realize `nginx conf` was ambiguous in meaning. I've added some logs to the q

Comment: This looks to be your problem - `File "/var/www/cards-against-humanity/app/routes.py", line 225, in game
    request.args.get('id')`

Comment: Looks like it is a python problem. Try running the app without using supervisor or nginx. do a `cd to-your-app.py`then execute `(venv) $ gunicorn -b localhost:8000 yourfile:app` and check that all pages and links are working properly. It looks like the url `/game/` is not working

Comment: That's just an internal error though, will return a 500 page. The app is still in development, and supposing an ID is provided the route will work (haven't added the catching yet). The button that is creating faulty redirects on localhost produces a perfectly fine redirect. All redirects are broken on the live website, returning a list of domains

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Removed `include proxy_params;` from the `location / {}` route. No idea what this does but it's working now.